# How do I make vim the default graphical text editor?

Tags: vim, default-programs

While trying to make vim default instead of gedit, I found this could be done two ways:

Use `defaults.list` and make `text/plain` (and others) point to `vim.desktop` (what is the format for creating `.desktop` files?)

Use `update-alternatives` and change `gnome-text-editor` (right now it has only one alternative, so I guess I have to install one more. How to do that?)

and which is the better way to do it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/268164/make-vim-default/268170#268170 Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 4):

OP [fixed the problem](https://superuser.com/questions/268164/make-vim-default/268170#268170) here:

> Ok, I have created `vim.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` and
>   modified `defaults.list` (in the same dir) to include
>
> ```
> text/plain=vim.desktop
> ```
>
> After that, `sudo update-mime` and its working! (*I am not sure
>   whether this step is require*)
>
> Clicking on a text file opens `vim`, not gvim, in terminal and `:q`
>   closes the terminal too.

Answer (score -1):

For a graphical environment I use something like this:

`Open Nautilus-RightClick on desired File-Properties-Open with...-Select`

Then point to a simple wrapper, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal.wrapper -e vim $*
```

It's not a global solution, though.

Comment: @N 1.1: Would be nice to leave a comment to explain the reason for downvoting. Or better comment *before* downvoting to give a chance to improve the answer. Maybe I misunderstood your question, but it works for me.

Comment: I agree with you but in fairness the -1 could have come from anybody with enough reputation. Not neccessarily N 1.1