# How do I set gvim as default application?

Tags: launcher, vim, default-programs, gvim

I compiled and installed vim 7.4 in Ubuntu 12.04. I want to set gvim as the default application for all text and C/C++ files.

I tried : Right click > Open With Other Application. But couldn't find Gvim in that list.
I also can't find Gvim in the launcher.

```
$which gvim
/usr/bin/gvim
```

Currently, I have to launch gvim from command line only.

```
$gvim filename &
```

How can I make gvim as the default editor when I open any text/ C/C++ files from file explorer?

Comment: That should be Right click -> properties -> Open With, actually. But anyway, read up on this: http://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/

Comment: @Xieerqi: can't fing gvim there.

Comment: @EliahKagan: looking into it

Comment: resolved. I referred this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/34061/how-do-i-make-vim-the-default-graphical-text-editor 
I had some problems creating a .desktop file, but this link is useful : http://askubuntu.com/questions/72535/creating-desktop-files-to-use-on-the-open-with-other-application-tab

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. It turned out to be a duplicate.

I referred this: [How do I make vim the default graphical text editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34061/how-do-i-make-vim-the-default-graphical-text-editor)

I had some problems creating a .desktop file, but this link is useful : [Creating .desktop files to use on the "Open with other application" tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72535/creating-desktop-files-to-use-on-the-open-with-other-application-tab)